# A simple drawing Example

Tags: android

This code should be drawing things, but it doesn't draw anything when I move my finger. Please help me debug it.

```
  @Override

  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
        return true;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // nothing to do 
        break;
      default:
        return false;
    }

    // Schedules a repaint.
    invalidate();
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: have you initialize path and paint with color objects, can you post more code..

Comment: definitely...I just kept it short

Comment: Refer [this](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/06/drawing-example-in-android.html) complete tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override

  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
  {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
        path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        return true;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.quadTo(eventX, eventY, (x + eventX)/2, (y + eventY)/2);
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
     path.reset();
        break;
      default:
        return false;
    }

    // Schedules a repaint.
    invalidate();
    return true;
  }
}
```

For more information take a look

http://code.google.com/p/strokesformartians/source/browse/trunk/src/se/combitech/strokesformartians/drawing/FingerPaint.java?r=120

This may help you.

Comment: IT is ridiculous that my paint.setColor was set to WHITE in a WHITE background, so everything was working but I cudnt get it. BTW, what is "quadTo" for...my code works without this.

Comment: How can I add a button which will CLEAR the canvas, I just need code for clearing lines..

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working example, You can draw free hand.

```
public class CanvasDrawingActivity extends  Activity   
{
    private ArrayList<Path> _graphics = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private Paint mPaint;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new DrawingPanel(this));
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFF00);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    }

    class DrawingPanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
    {
        private DrawingThread _thread;
        private Path path;

        public DrawingPanel(Context context) 
        {
            super(context);
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
            _thread = new DrawingThread(getHolder(), this);
        }


        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
        {
            synchronized (_thread.getSurfaceHolder()) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    path = new Path();
                    path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    _graphics.add(path);
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            for (Path path : _graphics) {
                //canvas.drawPoint(graphic.x, graphic.y, mPaint);
                canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                                   int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            _thread.setRunning(true);
            _thread.start();
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean retry = true;
            _thread.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    _thread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // we will try it again and again...
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class DrawingThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
        private DrawingPanel _panel;
        private boolean _run = false;

        public DrawingThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, DrawingPanel panel) {
            _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            _panel = panel;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            _run = run;
        }

        public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
            return _surfaceHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas c;
            while (_run) {
                c = null;
                try {
                    c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                        _panel.onDraw(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                    // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                    // inconsistent state
                    if (c != null) {
                        _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be as follows,

> [image]

Comment: Nice but TOOOO heavy for beginner like me :D

Comment: How can I add a button which will CLEAR the canvas, I just need code for clearing lines..

Comment: why it is slow when free hand drawing using surface view? The drawing comes after we release the touch why?